# Issue printing from an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, joptionpane

I'm having an issue printing out the newly created account from. It is showing up blank,i tried printing the array but it printed all the accounts. Does anyone know a way to print out the account by itself after its created or know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
ArrayList <BankAccount> bankArray = new ArrayList <BankAccount>();
private BankAccount

public void createAccount(String custName, String accNumber)
{
bankArray.add(new BankAccount(custName, accNumber));
printAccount();
}

public void printAccount()
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Account,"AccoDetails",);
}
```

Comment: This code doesnt look as if it compiles

Answer (score 1):

Add `newAccount = new BankAccount(custName, accNumber);
    bankArray.add(newAccount);`

Your newAccount is never set/ initialized to print.

Comment: I noticed that, but why is he saying it prints "all" accounts?  It should be printing "null".

Comment: @DanielKaplan He said when he tried printing the array it prints all. It is obvious as the array has the instance.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood what he was saying.